# Did the ancient Egyptians worship Cats and Dogs deities at the same period?

Tags: egyptian, symbolism, iconography

Did Egyptians worship feline and canine gods at the same period in history?

Comment: Hello @drago mothra and welcome to Myth and Folklore stackexchange. Take a bit of time to take our [tour](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tour). You seem to be all new on the Stackexchange network, so know that most of our Q&A doesn't allow too broad questions because they don't enable you to get one best and/or perfect answer. So I will suggest a modification to your question to limit it to the Egyptian culture.

Appart for that we expect people to show that they made some research on their own (at least a quick google research)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dog and Cat deities were worshiped together as early as the Second Dynasty (2890 BCE) in the forms of [Anubis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anubis) and [Bastet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastet), but the recorded worship of Anubis dates back to even the First Dynasty (3100 BCE). Bastet's worship centered around the city of [Bubastis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubastis), while Anubis took a central role in the afterlife as ruler of the underworld until this reign was passed to Osiris the evolving mythology of the Middle Kingdom.